# Proper way to write cypher and get all properties in Java

Tags: java, playframework, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am using the below code to get information from nodes:

```
public void  allResturants (){
        final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("MATCH (n:`Restaurant`) RETURN n.name as name, n.website as web, n.address as address LIMIT 25", null);
         for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
            String name=((String)row.get("name"));
            System.out.println("name is " + name);
         }
    }
```

Is there a way that I can select node direct by Query (like:`MATCH(n:Restaurant) RETURN n`)
and then iterate and get its properties.

This query actually looks very long with more number of attribute:

```
MATCH (n:`Restaurant`) RETURN n.name as name, n.website as web, n.address as address LIMIT 25;
```

I want something like `select * from tableName;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return whole node:

```
MATCH (n:`Restaurant`) RETURN n LIMIT 25;
```

and then in java code:

```
public void  allResturants (){
    final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("...", null);
     for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
        Node node = (Node) map.get("n"); // org.neo4j.graphdb.Node
        System.out.println("name is " + node.getProperty("name"));
     }
}
```

Works for both embedded and REST database.